# What is different of these: Host, Organizers, Sponsors, committee?

Tags: meaning

I don't know the different of "*Host, Organizers, Sponsors,  committee*" in the conference.

Comment: Please add what you have done searching for an answer before posing the question here. That provides context for a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

I presume a dictionary has not helped you in the context of a conference.

- I understand "host" as the person or organisation upon whose territory the conference is held. It may also be the person or organisation that is paying for the whole conference. The host is likely to have legal responsibilities for the event.
- The "organizers"  are those who decide on the structure, timing and content of the conference.
- The "sponsors" are those who are supporting the conference financially or in other external ways such as advertising (there may be many sponsors).
- The "committee" is a group of people who meet to decide on various things or actions needed to create the conference; there may be many committees (dealing with timetable, money, speakers, accommodation, social events).

People and organisations may overlap in all these roles.